# Login to user account with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log to my Garmin Connect account using selenium/python in PyCharm. I know there is an API but, as this is for training purpose, I really would like to reach my goal through the Website.

My code:

```
import scrapy
import time
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class ScrapgarminSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'scrapGarmin'

def start_requests(self):
    yield SeleniumRequest(
        url='https://connect.garmin.com/signin/',
        wait_time=3,
        callback=self.parse
    )

def parse(self, response):
    driver = response.meta['driver']

    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget']")))

    frameLogin=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget']")
    
    driver.switch_to.frame(frameLogin)

    champLogin=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='login_email']")
    champLogin.send_keys("my_email_here")
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    champPassword = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']")
    champPassword.send_keys("my_password_here")
    time.sleep(5)

    boutonSubmit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
    boutonSubmit.click()

    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"Current URL: {driver.current_url}")
```

If I do this, I have a:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe
```

Then I tried to click using javascript:

```
boutonSubmit = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", boutonSubmit)
```

In that case, there is no error message by my current URL remains the signin page. It does not enter the website.

Any idea please ? That would really help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You are saying that you can't click on the submit button but do you even need to do so?, you can simply just use the `\n` trick, or Keys.ENTER...

Why just not simplifying your code instead, you can make a lot of improvements. You may have your preferences but here is a simplified script with my methods. No need to set classes, multiple functions and setting variables for each action. I also see that you are using scrapy but you can also just install and use the chrome driver. All you have to do is download chromium chromedriver at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and then replace the path in `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Replace with chromedriver path")`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#setting up driver and loading page
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Replace with chromedriver path")
driver.get("https://connect.garmin.com/signin/") #loading page
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) #defining webdriver wait

#defining username and password, dont remove \n
username = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx\n' #\n will act as an enter key and automatically login after having entered the password without clicking on confirm

#locating the login script under a function to make things more "visible"
def login():
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget']"))) #switching frame
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys(username) #userame/email
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password'))).send_keys(password) #password

#calling the login function and printing "you're in!!" when logged in
login()
print("you're in!!")
print('Url: ', driver.current_url)
```

You can locate elements by ID, or NAME which are much more simple and shorter than the XPATH.
I can also see that you define vairiables which is ok but then you 're-call' the variable adding a `.send_keys` function, you can simply add it at the end:

```
test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xxx")
test.send_keys("hello")
```

to

```
test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xxx").send_keys("hello")
```

You can also remove the variable and just make a little `#` note of the function.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xxx").send_keys("hello") #test
```

I also recommend using the `driver.wait` function which is brilliant to not get any errors or having to wait extra time with `time.sleep()` for example, as you see I define the waiting function at the beginning.

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'xxx'))).send_keys(hello)` #test
```

Some more tips to learn selenium:

- do not stay stuck in the tutorial hell, make projects, preferably on your own or patchwork
- take notes of specific scripts when you learn something new
- some projects ideas: type bot on online type learning sites, auto clicker etc...
- just have fun while learning

Simple and effective, have a nice day.

Comment: wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='gauth-widget-frame-gauth-widget']"))) a 1 liner for the frame switch.

Comment: Also use element_to_be_clickable instead of visibility_of_element_located.

Comment: Could go with with either Keys.ENTER or submit button either way.